# Solaris Client 8.1.7 Can't connect to Oracle 12C R1

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, solaris, oracle8i

In grace of this parameter of Oracle 12c R1 sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
```

I can connect from a 8.1.7 Windows client without issues.

However, trying to do the same from Solaris 8.1.7 client, I get following errors:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 8.1.7.0.0 - Production on Mon Jul 15 13:19:21 2019

(c) Copyright 2000 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
SP2-0575: Use of Oracle SQL feature not in SQL92 Entry Level.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select * from dual;
select * from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03137: TTC protocol internal error : [kpoal8-3] [393235] [] [] [] [] [] []
SQL>
```

Using Solaris 11

Comment: According to My Oracle Support document "Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)", this combination of client and server was never officially supported.  Although it's possible you'll get lucky and find a combination that works.  Are the Windows and Solaris clients both 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Both clients are 32 bits. One curious thing is that I have in the same Solaris machine a 806 client which can connect to 12c without issues

Comment: Check out "Bug 20903906 - ORA-3137 "TTC protocol internal error" [kpoal8-3] from 8i client to 12c server (Doc ID 20903906.8)", which seems to imply this is an issue with the *server*, not the client.  But that doesn't explain why it works in Windows but not Solaris.  Are there any differences in the client sqlnet.ora files?

Comment: I have the same sqlnet.ora. I will try that database patch. Thanks

Comment: @JonHeller Worked, thanks a lot buddy.